# How to resolve error: not assignable to parameter of type '"disconnect"'?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I have the following test in which I would like to emit a particular event, namely an unhandledRejection process:

```
    describe('Processes Tests', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        sinon.restore();
    });
it('Check unhandledRejection process Spied On', () => {
        var spy = sinon.spy();
        process.on('unhandledRejection', spy);
        process.emit('unhandledRejection');
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
      });
});
```

I have the following error on the line `process.emit('unhandledRejection')`:

```
Argument of type '"unhandledRejection"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"disconnect"'.
```

Might anyone know why that is and how I may be able to resolve it so that I can test this process? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('Processes Tests', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        sinon.restore();
    });
    it('Check unhandledRejection process Spied On', () => {
        var spy = sinon.spy();
        process.on('unhandledRejection', spy);
        process.emit('unhandledRejection', 'reason', new Promise(() => {}));
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
    });
});
```

You forgot 2 more parameters

I didn't find it in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/) about this method, but I did find it in the [types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/process.d.ts#L310)